# Why does OnLocationChanged called twice every second?

Tags: java, android, localization, gps, on-location-changed

I have an Android Application that write one line in a file every time the method `OnLocationChanged()` is called. Data inside each line is separated by a semicolon. I store the epoch time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`), the latitude and the longitude of the new location:

File example 1:

> 147729480**4758**;45.17358813287331;5.750043562562213
>   147729480**5758**;45.17358813287331;5.750043562562213

Between those two lines, there is 1 second gap so everything is fine.

Most of the time, it works. But sometimes, every second, it writes two lines :

File example 2:

> 147729480**6761**;45.17358813287331;5.750043562562213
>   1477294806776;45.17358813287331;5.750043562562213
>   147729480**7767**;45.17358813287331;5.750043562562213
>   1477294807779;45.17358813287331;5.750043562562213

`OnLocationChanged` is called twice every second with a 15 millis gap.

I could not find a way to reproduce this bug. It is erratic.

Here is how I implement the location provider :

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);  
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0,MainActivity.this);
```

My `MainActivity` implements `LocationListener`.

Here is how I write data to the file :

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        try {
            File dataFile = new File(saveFileFlyData);
            if(!dataFile.exists())
                dataFile.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(dataFile, true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            try {

                if(mCurrentLocation != null)
                {
                    osw.write(System.currentTimeMillis() +
                            ";" + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() +
                            ";" + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+
                            "\n"
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    osw.write(0 +
                            ";" + 0 +
                            ";" + 0+
                            "\n"
                    );
                }

                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

I cant see why it works from time to time.

Comment: The constant file operations may occasionally mess up your application's timing if there's something else going on in the devices file system at the same time. You might see some longer than 1 second gaps in your log in addition to the shorter than 1 second gaps. The location updates probably come as expected every 1 second if you comment out the file operations. (This is just a somewhat educated guess.)